# What's the difference between monodis and ikdasm?

Tags: mono

I am using mono 3.8.0, after installation, i find there are two deassemblier programe in mono "bin" directory, "monodis" and "ikdasm"

During test, i find the generated il file is different, the generated file by "ikdasm" is same as "ildasm.exe" in MS .Net, but "monodis" have a little different case such as "ctor" -> 'ctor' with single quote, two array dimension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

monodis is an old version, written in C that also provides a few small features useful in understanding the metadata format (see --help).
ikdasm is written in C# and is probably more appropriate as a disassembler.

Comment: do you have any offical materials about this?

Comment: Not sure what kind of official material you want. If it helps, I'm officially the monodis author;-).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/#miscellaneous-tools

> - monodis: IL disassembler and metadata explorer
> - ikdasm: IL disassembler, more robust, but lacks some of the metadata features of monodis.

Other resources:

https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodis/
https://github.com/mono/ikdasm