# .net-core: Equivalent of ILDASM / ILASM

Tags: linux, .net-core, ildasm, ilasm

Is there the equivalent of ILDASM / ILASM for the .net-core?

Specifically, I'm looking for something that runs on Linux (Hence why the .net-core).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both the ildasm and ilasm tools are built with CoreCLR from this repo: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr. They include similar functionality as the versions shipped with Windows (sans GUI, etc.).

There are nuget packages shipped that include them as well (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ildasm), but they are platform-specific and also require a matching version of CoreCLR to use, so they are not straightforward to consume via nuget. The easiest way to run these on your platform is to just build them from source from the coreclr repo.

Comment: That's a much better answer than mine. Thank-you for posting this. I'm not sure how I missed coreCLR, that may solve some problems.

Comment: Is there a version of these tools already compiled or do I to build the repository to get them?

Comment: @JavierHolguera, like I mentioned above, you can download and use them from the nuget packages, but you'd need to download the right individual nuget package for your operating system.

Answer (score 4):

It does not appear there is a native Microsoft tool that serves these functions on Linux and it is not currently built into the dot-net-core.

However, Mono allows the assembly and disassembly of IL code:

[Installation Instructions can be found here.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/)

What you are looking for is:

```
ilasm - For assembling
monodis - For disassembling
```

These are found in the package mono-utils:

e.g. On Debian 8 I did the following:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian jessie" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install mono-devel mono-utils
```

However, FYI, for those trying to create exports, Mono does not appear to handle the x64 export syntax.

Comment: Worth noting that [`ikdasm` is better suited for disassembly than `monodis`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26373496/21501).

Answer (score 3):

Let's 'install' *ildasm* tool using related nuget-package:

- define [RID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) (Runtime Identifier)

```sh
dotnet --info

# execution result
..
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64 # <----
..
```

- download the package *runtime.{RID}.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm*. For my case it is: [runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm/)
- unarchive it and extract executable file *'/runtimes/{RID}/native/ildasm'*
- grant it execution permission and copy to .NET runtime folder (call *dotnet --list-runtimes* to list runtimes)

```sh
chmod +x ildasm
sudo mv ildasm /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/{version}/
```

- create symlink

```sh
ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/{version}/ildasm ildasm
```

- run ildasm

```sh
./ildasm {path}/project.dll >> {path}/project.il
```

The same steps are applicable for [ilasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm/).

---

As an alternate way consider using [dotnet-ildasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ildasm/) tool:

```sh
# install .net core runtime if required
# sudo apt-get update; \
#   sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
#   sudo apt-get update && \
#   sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-3.0

# find required tool
dotnet tool search ildasm
# output:
# Package ID         Latest Version      Authors      Downloads      Verified
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dotnet-ildasm      0.12.2              pjbgf        100154                 
# dotasm             1.0.1               DotAsm       434 

# install tool
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ildasm
```

Output IL to file:

```sh
# go to project folder
cd ../project/bin/Debug/netx.x

dotnet ildasm program.dll -o program.il
```

Comment: These steps work really well, but it should be noted that you don't need to put the executable in the same location as your installed SDK.
It's a native executable that doesn't depends on the .Net runtime or libraries, so you can keep it wherever you like.