# Assembly references internals: [mscorlib]System.Console is emitted and yet no mscorlib exists in references

Tags: .net, .net-core

This question is about internals of assembly references.

.Net Core 1.1 Hello world console application assembly (created from `dotnet new console`) emits no reference to `mscorlib`, only to `System.Runtime` and `System.Console`, and yet it emits call to `[mscorlib]System.Console`.

How is that possible?

```
.assembly extern System.Runtime
{
  .ver 4:1:0:0
  .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A ) // .?_....:
}
.assembly extern System.Console
{
  .ver 4:0:0:0
  .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A ) // .?_....:
}
.assembly 'console1'
...
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
...
    IL_0006:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)

...
```

Comment: Which version of the tooling are you using? if I try to reproduce this with 1.0.4, I get `call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)`

Comment: @MartinUllrich Current .Net Core 1.1 which comes with tooling 1.0.4. I'm using Mac

Comment: @HansPassant do you know where this would come in here? the reference assembly that is compiled against is built from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Console/ref/System.Console.cs in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in disassembly tool.

Since .NET Core doesn't come with `ildasm` I used `monodis` from Mono. 
Now I followed [.net-core: Equivalent of ILDASM / ILASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979851/net-core-equivalent-of-ildasm-ilasm) to compile ildasm for Mac form C++ sources, and now:

```
$ monodis bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/console1.dll | grep WriteLine
    IL_0006:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
$ ildasm bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/console1.dll | grep WriteLine
    IL_0006:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```